# Generics java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, selenium, generics

can someone please explain how to fix this code? Whenever i run `LoginTest` i get `java.lang.ClassCastException: features.pages.HomePage cannot be cast to features.pages.LoginPage`.Both classes are subclass to BasePage and casting without generics works fine

```
public class Base {

public static BasePage currentPage;

public <T extends BasePage> T GetInstance(Class<T> page) {
    Object obj = PageFactory.initElements(DriverContext.Driver, page);
    return page.cast(obj);
}}
```

BasePage.java

```
public abstract class BasePage extends Base {


public <T extends BasePage> T As(Class<T> pageInstance) {
    try {
        return (T) this;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}}
```

LoginPage.java

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

public HomePage login(String username, String password) {
    txtUserName.sendKeys(username);
    txtPassword.sendKeys(password);
    btnLogin.submit();

    return GetInstance(HomePage.class);
}}
```

LoginTest.java

```
public class LoginTest extends Base{
@Test
public void Login() {

    currentPage = GetInstance(HomePage.class);
    currentPage.As(HomePage.class).clickLogin();
    // breaks at login()
    currentPage.As(LoginPage.class).login("admin", "password");
```

Comment: What do you mean casting without generics works fine? You are trying to cast two different objects to each other. Since the `login` method returns an `HomePage` instance, why don't you assign the return value of said method to the `currentPage` variable?

Comment: Unless `HomePage` is a superclass of `LoginPage`, you cannot cast a `HomePage` to a `LoginPage`. Note: this is nothing to do with generics per se, this is just straight-up reference type casting.

Comment: I think if you had `CurrentPage = GetInstance(BasePage.class)` there might be some hope, but because you've arranged for it to be an instance of HomePage at the beginning, I wouldn't expect the cast to work.

Comment: Although both classes are subclasses of BasePage, you can not cast from subclass to subclass. Both are reference types, for those Java only knows up- and downcasting.

Comment: And please, follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variables and methods always start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Found what the error was. I wasn't assigning return value to `currentProject` attribute.

changing

```
currentPage = GetInstance(HomePage.class);
currentPage.As(HomePage.class).clickLogin();
currentPage.As(LoginPage.class).login("admin", "password");`
```

to

```
currentPage = GetInstance(HomePage.class);
currentPage = currentPage.As(HomePage.class).clickLogin();
currentPage.As(LoginPage.class).login("admin", "password");`
```

fixed the issue.